# How to send a file via email with Mono fro Android

Tags: sendmail, xamarin.android

This sends the mail but the attachment doesn't appear.

```
{
        Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
        mailIntent.SetType("text/csv");

        mailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[]{"rommyce@hotmail.com"});
        string path = root + nameFile;


        mailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse (@"file:/" + path));

        StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(mailIntent, "Send mail..."));
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
        mailIntent.SetType("text/csv");

        mailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[]{"xxxxxxr@hotmail.com"});
        //string path = root + nameFile;

        mailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file:///sdcard/ejemplo.csv"));

        StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(mailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```